# Do automata theory questions belong here or on Computer Science?

Tags: discussion, questions, computer-science

I have a question regarding automata theory that I think is more theoretical than simple "How do you translate this PDA to a CFG?" stuff that would obviously seem to go into Computer Science.  I, however, can see a good argument that all automata theory questions should now go into Computer Science.   Does automata theory still belong here at all?

Comment: Automata counts as mathematics. It also counts as computer science. I would pick your favourite site and if you haven't received a decent answer within, say, a week then post on the other site (and link to the original).

Comment: We do have an [tag:automata] tag, and a [tag:formal-languages] tag. Both are on-topic. I see no reason to insist that automata theory questions be sent elsewhere.

Comment: Or should they automata-cally be migrated to CS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, [automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) questions are considered on topic here.  Regarding whether you should ask here or on CS, I would recommend asking wherever you think the question has a better chance of getting a good answer.